# Error 403 localhost Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Tags: php

Please help!
I'm getting following error when I try to log in:

**Access forbidden!**

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

**Error 403**

localhost
*Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7*

Code of my login.php is following:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("config.php");
require("functions.php");
$db = mysql_connect($localhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "' AND password     = '" . $_POST['password'] . "';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrows == 1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['active'] == 1) {
session_register("USERNAME");
session_register("USERID");
$_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['USERID'] = $row['id'];
switch($_GET['ref']) {
case "addbid":
header("Location: " . $config_basedir
. "/itemdetails.php?id=" . $_GET['id'] . "#bidbox");
break;
case "newitem":
header("Location: " . $config_basedir . "/newitem.php");
break;
case "images":
header("Location: " . $config_basedir
. "/addimages.php?id=" . $_GET['id']);
break;
default:
header("Location: " . $config_basedir);
break;
}
}
else {
require("header.php");
echo "This account is not verified yet. You were
emailed a link to verify the account. Please click on the
link in the email to continue.";
}
}
else {
header("Location: " . $config_basedir . "/login.php?error=1");
}
}
else {
require("header.php");
echo "<h1>Login</h1>";

if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
echo "Incorrect login, please try again!";
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo
pf_script_with_get($SCRIPT_NAME); ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
Don't have an account? Go and <a href="register.php">Register</a>!
<?php
}
require("footer.php");
?>
```

After following some suggestions on this site on other questions, I changed the code in  httpd.conf which is following:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
     Require all denied
</Directory>
```

and also:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

users table in database:

id int (11) AUTO_INCREMENT Primary
username varchar(10) latin1_swedish-ci
password varchar(10) latin1_swedish-ci
email varchar(100) latin1_swedish-ci
verifystring varchar(20) latin1_swedish-ci
active tinyint(4)

Comment: other pages are opening properly?

Comment: A file listing (including hidden files and attributes) of the directory where the file lies would be more helpful than the source code.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, yeah other pages are opening properly and can also access database. For example my itemdetails.php can show what items are in the database.

Comment: I think I'll log in as `Admin'--`. Anyway when do you get the error (when requesting the login page, after supplying valid credentials, ...?). What URL is being accessed when you get the error (faulty redirect?)? What is in the server logs?

Comment: @CodeCaster, thank you for replying.
When I click on Login i.e submitting username and password, then only I get this error. 
I get the following URL on my browser after getting the error:
http://localhost/auction/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Undefined%20variable:%20SCRIPT_NAME%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:/xampp/htdocs/auction/login.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E58%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E

I don't know, how to see server logs.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I have following files in my directory:
bar.php
config.php
edititem.php
footer.php
functions.php
header.php
index.php
itemdetails.php
login.php
logout.php
register.php

and I don't have any hidden files in the folder. Other file can access database, but it's only login.php and register.php which is showing error when I send the login details.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `login` and `register` processes try to be handled through SSL connection, but you are not enabled for SSL connection. if you use a script package. go to admin panel and disable SSL connection.